# jQuery: Can't select just appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is what happens on event:

```
$('div#pages').append($('<div class="page" id="test">...</div>'));
```

And then, on another event it fails doing this:

```
var page = $('div.page#test'); // returns empty array
```

I've debugged, and the appended html appears in the document structure after appending, but fails to get selected. Doing the same in browser console works perfectly.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Your first code snippet has a missing parenthesis. Is that a typo? Also, how are you verifying the order of the events?

Comment: `$('#test')` should suffice, as ids should be unique. There is no reason to chain a class and an id in your selector.

Comment: @StephenThomas it was typo while writing the post (edited). Well, it's not necessarily on event, after the div was appended, I go to dev tools in browser, make sure that the div is there, go to console, try to select it with jquery - no success.

Comment: @watson thanks for reminding, but there can be also other divs like `<div class="thread" id="test">...`

Comment: @Acute, if you have multiple elements with the same `id`, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the rest of your code. I would guess the variable `page` is being declared before the element is added. Also, don't use multiple identical ID's on your page. If they need to be the same string, use a class instead.

Comment: @StephenThomas thanks, useful. Luckily, I don't have duplicate ids yet :-P And suddenly the `find()` finds it, while the usual `$('')` select doesn't...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `.find()` http://api.jquery.com/find

```
var page = $('div#pages').find('div.page#test');
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question

Comment: it does the job, can you explain why the usual select doesn't work?

Comment: @Acute I think it has to do with a scope issue. Like if you did the regular selector without .find(), in the same function/event as when you appended it, then it would work. However, since your doing them in two different functions/events, or 1 inside the function and another outside, you need to use .find() since the DOM couldn't find it the first time around. Sorry, not the best at explaining

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian actually, you did pretty well!

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use **live** method:

```
$('.element').live('click', function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution that works fine for appended elements.
[image]

Comment: this is the only one that works for me, the reason live isn't available is because it has been deprecated. I do not know for the rest

Comment: This is great. Should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, found that if I added the listener before adding the div, it wouldn't find the div. Make sure to add the listener after making the object.

Comment: How to add the listener?

Answer (score 2):

I had to use a hack to get around this problem recently when I was dynamically inserting `<select>` elements. I changed this:

```
var $item = $('#appendedItem1'); // returns: []
```

to this:

```
var $item = $(document.getElementById('appendedItem1')); // returns: [select#appendedItem1]
```

I know it seems like it should be the exact same thing, but only the second one works.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me a lot more often than I would like. I've tried just about everything and while some solutions work in certain scenarios or browsers, they don't work in others. Some of the most common solutions I've tried were:

Waiting for DOM / element to be ready before selecting or manipulating it (this is so simple but actually works a lot of the time):

```
$('#element').ready(() => {
    // Get or modify element
});
```

Using `find` (see CRABOLO's answer). Here is another example:

```
// Create element
let div = $('<div></div>');
// Use element to find child
let child = div.find('#element');
// Or
let child = $('#element', div);
```

If you're trying to listen to events triggered by an appended element, `on` should work for you most of the time since it can trigger for all future elements matching a selector (see Md Shahriar's answer). Here is another example:

```
$(document).on('event', '.element', function() {
    // "event" has been triggered on a ".element"
});
```

And an example [from the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**If none of the other solutions work for you**, you can always try to check manually using an `Interval`. This is the only way I've been able to solve this issue in certain situations:

```
/* Usage:
   onEditable('#element', () => {
       // Element is now for sure ready to be selected or modified.
   });
*/
function onEditable(selector, callback){
    if($(selector)[0]){
        callback();
        return;
    }

    let s = setInterval(() => {
        // Check if jQuery can find the element
        if($(selector)[0]){
            // Call callback function
            clearInterval(s);
            callback();
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

**I can't stress this enough; if you can find another solution that works for you, use that instead, since this doesn't work based on events and takes up a lot more computer resources.**

Hope this helps someone having the same issues I did :).

Answer (score -2):

missed quotes on class name `page`

Also missed `)` for `append()`

Should be

```
    $('div#pages').append($('<div class="page" id="test">...</div>'));
```

instead of

```
$('div#pages').append($('<div class=page id="test">...</div>');
```

Comment: While this is something that should be fixed, it's unlikely this is the cause of the issue.  The question states that the element appears as expected after the append.

Comment: no, that's not a problem, and it was my typo %) fixed)

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary on modern browsers.