# external javascript can't get elements inside other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm new to javascript and have encountered following problem without finding a solution.

Background:

So I'm working in Eclipse to make a component for Design Studio and one of the things you can do is add additional properties for the component so people can change the component themselves.

So there is an additional_properties_sheet.html in which i have written following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Annotation property sheet</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="somepath/sdk_propertysheets_handler.js"></script>
    <script src="additional_properties_sheet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Click me</button>
    </form>
    <script src="../js/component.js"></script>
</body>
```

and in my component.js I have something like this (didn't include all code cause it's way to much)

```
define(["sap/designstudio/sdk/component", "d3", "../js/ckeditor/ckeditor", "css!../css/component.css"], function(Component, d3, ckeditor, css) {
Component.subclass("com.sap.sample.annotation.Annotation", function() {
//dropdown voor de CommentObj
        commObjDropdown = theDiagram.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("x", "5%")
        .attr("y", "76%")
        .attr("width", "226")
        .attr("height", "30")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html('<select name="commObjs" id="commObjs" class="commObjs"></select>');
        $('#commObjs').append($('<option/>').attr("value", "0").text("--- Select an object ---"));

});

function test(){

alert($('#commObjs'));
alert(document.getElementById("commObjs"));


}
```

But when I click the button it always returns 'null'.
My path to the js is correct if I just write alert("hello"); in my test function the output is fine I just can't get the element from the other function. I would like to retrieve the element so i can make an input box to add options to the dropdown.

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following which I think is more correct but still fails at the moment, in my component.js i changed this:

```
var retrieveObj;
define(["sap/designstudio/sdk/component", "d3", "../js/ckeditor/ckeditor", "css!../css/component.css"], function(Component, d3, ckeditor, css) {
Component.subclass("com.sap.sample.annotation.Annotation", function() {
//dropdown voor de CommentObj
        commObjDropdown = theDiagram.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("x", "5%")
        .attr("y", "76%")
        .attr("width", "226")
        .attr("height", "30")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html('<select name="commObjs" id="commObjs" class="commObjs"></select>');
        $('#commObjs').append($('<option/>').attr("value", "0").text("--- Select an object ---"));

        retrieveObj = document.getElementById("commObjs");
        alert(retrieveObj);
});


function test(){

alert($('#commObjs'));
alert(document.getElementById("commObjs"));
alert(retrieveObj);
}
```

So in short I declared a global variable and in the function itself the alert displays the htmlObject but still in the test() function it says undefined now.

Comment: That's the idea of the scope, you can't access into functions, only outside.

Comment: Try loading the component.js in the head section using `script src`

Comment: @vinothh already tried this before didn't work either thats why I moved it down cause some people said it was loaded before the element was created.

Comment: either the element does not exist or you have multiple elements on the page with the same id or that code is inside an iframe....

Comment: @epascarello as you can see in my code that I added I did create the element and it also shows in my browser when I test it. I just checked I only have one element with the id 'commObjs'. And it is not used in an iframe, any other ideas i can check?

Comment: this might be something similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308733/jquery-cant-select-just-appended-element

Comment: @JordyDieltjens not really since in my test() function i can't get any elements from my main function (probably because they aren't in the same scope as someone pointed me out), so I don't have any elements to which i can use .find()

Comment: Not even the TheDiagram?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens nope cause as i said i didn't include all the code. all my code is in the main function including thediagram and all of my other elements that i created. this is because originally i only needed 1function to be loaded as i run my component and this all worked. But now they asked me to make the component adaptable. so now i have to use the additional property sheet were they can change the selction and so now i have to create another function outside the main function to get objects from the main function but this seems to be a real struggle