# Add active class to the first element of the tabs that were dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, tabs

I build these dynamic tabs via jQuery. My idea tab is to select the first element, nav + tab content.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs syslogNavTabs"> //dynamic tabs
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content syslogTabContent"> //dynamic tab contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ideal Result**

[image]

I created them like so

```
var loopFinished     = false; 

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/kubes/up/default/'  + '{{ Request::segment(3) }}',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    success: function(response){
        // console.log(response);

        var namespace = response.metadata.namespace;
        var pod       = response.metadata.name;

        var upcchartCpuUrl  = "{{ env('MONITORING_CHARTS_URL') }}" + "/d-solo/330/kubernetes-pods-metrics?orgId=1&from=-6h&to=now&var-datasource=Prometheus&var-namespace="+namespace+"&var-pod="+pod+"&panelId=20";

        var upcchartMemoryUrl  = "{{ env('MONITORING_CHARTS_URL') }}" + "/d-solo/330/kubernetes-pods-metrics?orgId=1&from=-6h&to=now&var-datasource=Prometheus&var-namespace="+namespace+"&var-pod="+pod+"&panelId=18";


        $('.upcchart-cpu iframe').attr('src', upcchartCpuUrl);
        $('.upcchart-memory iframe').attr('src', upcchartMemoryUrl);


        var containers       = response.spec.containers;

        for (i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {

            var data       = {};
            data.nameSpace = namespace;
            data.podName   = pod;
            data.container = containers[i].name;

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/kubes/api/log',
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                },
                data: data,
                success: function(response){

                    var syslogNavTabs = 
                    `<li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#${response.container}" aria-expanded="true"> ${response.container}</a></li>`;

                    var syslogTabContent = `
                    <div id="${response.container}" class="tab-pane">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <pre style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto; height: 500px;">${response.data}</pre>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

                    $('.syslogNavTabs').append(syslogNavTabs);
                    $('.syslogTabContent').append(syslogTabContent);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });


            loopFinished = true; 
        }
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I've tried

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    $('.syslogNavTabs .nav-link:first').addClass('active');
    $('.syslogTabContent .tab-pane:first').addClass('active');
});
```

and also tried

```
var loopFinished     = false;
```

and

```
loopFinished = true;
```

at the end of my for loop and does a check

```
if(loopFinished){
    $('.syslogNavTabs .nav-link:first').addClass('active');
    $('.syslogTabContent .tab-pane:first').addClass('active');
}
```

None is working. I kept getting **inactive tabs looks**

[image]

## Note :

If I select on them, they started to show contents properly.

If I entered this on the Console of my Chrome.

```
$('.syslogNavTabs .nav-link:first').addClass('active');
$('.syslogTabContent .tab-pane:first').addClass('active');
```

I got the active classes to add also.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select elements directly that are just appended to the page, but you could try to use jquery `.find` like from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308733/jquery-cant-select-just-appended-element/22308800)

```
$('.syslogNavTabs').find('.nav-link:first').addClass('active');
$('.syslogTabContent').find('.tab-pane:first').addClass('active');
```

or you can change the logic by adding the class in the variable string you've created, here's an example

```
var syslogNavTabs = `<li><a class="nav-link ${i == 0 ? 'active' : ''}">...</li>`
```

Comment: I like the options. I’ll try them out. Thanks 

Comment: I got syntac error on your second suggestion.

Comment: @cyb3rZ I am so sorry, I updated the code. The cause of the error is backtick in the [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) just remove backtick before `${` and after `}`. It should be working.

Comment: I will try again.